# cakephp application design query

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization

I am really a new bee in cakephp development. I've got a design question and would like to get some ideas.

The web application is for a big corporation and each child companies underneath is exactly the same. one child company can not see data from another child company. so at this stage my query is should I build build separate replicated apps, each represent one child company. if so then data aggregation would be a big job in terms of running overall reports. the other option is to build one big application and display/hide data based on the user logged in (user and location of the company).

the next big problem is within each small company there are different units and only certain data is visible across. for example publication department can see customer details but not customer's order history details. from each company one admin user have a right to see all the details. its like each business unit represent a module with certain data visibility. I know cake has fantastic authentication module to handle this but what I need to know is should I put authentication based on controller level or action level? so then each business unit = one big controller

hope this description will give you some sort of vague idea of what i am trying to build.

thanks in advance

Comment: This question unfortunately is subjective. You need to ask specific questions on stackoverflow. Please refer to the following links: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: thanks for comments i know its too subjective but thinking about a big picture, a whole system design and not knowing cake too well makes it difficult to start. the only reason i ask this question is so that i do not have to revisiting build code in future. I think start with best practice is better idea. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACL.Take a look here [ACL tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) or use a plugin like [Alaxos Plugin](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0)

Comment: I need more information because you question is too subjective but...  you can build an web service with an API and then make small apps using what API but thats more difficult to build and maintain. Y always suggest using an API for big projects where small apps creates or consume data.If you need more information please be more specific.

Comment: thanks again. let me clarify with an example. each company have customer, sales, publication, production units. when a user from New York publication department login in to the system, user can only see (CRUD) data related to publication model and associated model for new york region. against when user from London production department logs in he/she can only view data related to production line in London. AT the same time when an admin user logs in he has complete visibility of data/information across different location and different department. hope this clarify.

Comment: Then use ACL .that should be enough.